# Freestyle lines not showing up in final render

Tags: rendering, freestyle

I'm trying to render a cartoon image with Freestyle lines. The lines render perfectly in the preview window, but they do not show up on actual render output. Could someone please help me with this?

**View my render settings:**

[image]
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/rd.temp/RenderTab.PNG

**View my scene settings:**
[image]

Comment: What are you render layer settings, is the freestyle layer active? Do you have compositing enabled, how are your nodes setup?

Comment: I have compositing enabled, but there's not really any compositing going on. I have the render layer input node connected directly to the composite output node. The Freestyle layer is active.

Comment: You'll probably have to provide more information to diagnose the problem, I don't think it's possible to fix this from these two screenshots alone.

Comment: I'm using Blender Internal engine if that helps. It's more than likely related to the rendering settings because Freestyle is working perfectly in the viewport. I'll play around with it some more and post about anything I find.

Comment: It seems that I solved the problem. I had "culling" turned on in the Freestyle settings to hide the renderings of lines that aren't visible to the camera. For some reason the camera doesn't see the model for mapping during the freestyle rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I solved the problem. I had "culling" turned on in the Freestyle settings to hide the renderings of lines that aren't visible to the camera. For some reason the camera doesn't see the model for mapping during the freestyle rendering.